# Call encryption method, not working?

Tags: php, oop, encryption

I've got a class called Membership, in which i have a two methods. The first one's called validateUser, and the second one is called encryptPass. The problem is that even though i call the encryptPass method, it returns the original password. In other words; it doesn't seem like it's actually returning the data or it's not calling the method correctly?

I'm new to OOP so don't judge me for not knowing very much now.

This is how it looks were i call the method:

```
  //validate password and hash it if valid
  if(strlen($password) > 25 || strlen($password) < 4) {
   $password = $this->encryptPass($password);
   $errorArray[] = "Löenordet måste vara mellan 4-25 tecken långt.";
  }
```

And this is how the actual encryptPass method looks like:

```
 function encryptPass($password) {
  $salt = substr($password, 2, 4);
  $password = md5(md5($password));
  $password = substr($password, 0, 20) . $salt . substr($password, 0, 20);
  $password = md5($password);
  return $password;
 }
```

I threw together a custom encryption algorithm as you can see, maybe i screwed up there somehow?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `md5` is not encryption, it is a one-way (albeit [insecure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5#Collision_vulnerabilities)/compromised) [hashing function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function).

Comment: This is not a "custom encryption algorithm", and you're producing a less secure hash than you would have with a single call of `md5()`.

Comment: How is that? How could you possibly decrypt that hash without knowing the "encryption algorithm"? If it's not an encryption algorithm, what'd you call it?

Comment: @Nike It's called a "hash", and the whole point is that you can't decrypt it - it's one way.  Encryption is reversible - you can take an encrypted string and reproduce the original via decryption.  There is no decryption function for `md5()`.

Comment: Well okey, that makes sense. But what's the real point with being able to decrypt an algorithm? Unless you need to know the password without knowing it, there's no point with it, right? It works good if you know the password -  the hash always become the same.

Comment: The whole point of decryption is that you can prevent people from reading something without having to first decrypt it. I'm not suggesting that you use encryption on your passwords, I'm simply saying that you're misusing the term 'encryption'. And PS: Please, please replace your "custom algorithm" with a single call to `md5()`  (or better yet, [`hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php))

Comment: I understand that, so you're saying that you (or anyone else) could figure out the password if i gave you a hash from this function (if you didn't know the structure ofc)? It's first hashed twise, and then cut in two different pieces with some salt in the middle, and then hashed once more. You'd need to know all of that, right? Sorry for all the questions, i just wanna be sure of what i know.

Answer (score 1):

Your encryptPass() method isn't getting called unless your $password string is more than 25 characters or less than 4.  Are you sure that's the correct logic?

Comment: Yup you're right. That's not really what i was trying to do. I threw in an "else" and changed the if query to: if(strlen($password) > 4 && strlen($password) < 25), it works now. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

You're checking `if(strlen($password) > 25 || strlen($password) < 4)`, which in English is "if the length of the string is greater than 25 or less than 4", which is probably not the correct logic. You probably meant to do

```
if (strlen($password) > 4 && strlen($password) < 25)
```

which would check for a password that is between 5 and 24 characters long, or

```
if (strlen($password) >= 4 && strlen($password) <= 25)
```

if you want to check for a password between 4 and 25 characters long.